# xquery expression to return a link text only if it contains within it a specific string

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to extract some links from a XML document (links are in same format as on html pages).

Now for eg a link is "http://xyz.com/start/tyu/a.html" and another is "http://ert.com/tyu/b.html" while a third link is "http://asdf.com/ghjk/c.html"

From the above 3 links (which I have with me using a for clause in a FLWOR expression)...I want only the links which contain within them a string "tyu" to be selected-- I thought of using substring for this, but substring requires start and end positions to be specified- whereas in my scenario, I dont know at which position the desired string will be.

How do I do substring matching in such a scenario, i.e. where exact position for occurrence of substring, is not known? I can use XQuery 1.0 for this purpose.

Finally, I want to extract the link URL, as well as link text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [fn:contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-contains):

```
   for $link in
   (
     <a href="http://xyz.com/start/tyu/a.html">first link</a>,
     <a href="http://ert.com/tyu/b.html">second link</a>,
     <a href="http://asdf.com/ghjk/c.html">third link</a>
   )
   where contains($link/@href, "tyu")
   return <link url="{$link/@href}" text="{$link}"/>
```